# I got message Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance when i click button

Tags: laravel, routes

I got error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\Kerja\cst-rekap\resources\views\image_rekap.blade.php)"\

This my blade`image_rekap.blade.php`

```
@extends('layout.admin')

@push('css')

@section('content')
  <body>
    <h1 class="text-center mb-4" >Data Rekap</h1>
    <div class="container mb-5">
        <h2>Dokumentasi  Customer : <span class="text-primary">{{$data->customer}}</span> </h2>
          <a href="/rekap" class="btn btn-primary">Kembali</a>
          <button href="/download_image/{{ $images->id }}" class="btn btn-primary center">DOWNLOAD</button>
          @foreach ($images as $image)
          <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="card" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <img src="{{asset('images_rekap/'.$image->image)}}" class="card-img-top mb-2">
                      <a href="/deleteimagerekap/{{ $image->id }}" class="btn btn-primary center">HAPUS</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @push('script')
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  @endpush
  </body>
@endsection
```

and this `RekapController`

```
public function download_image($id)
{

$images = image_rekap::where('rekap_id',$id)->get();

$images = [];
foreach ($images as $i => $image) {
    $images[$image->id] = public_path(). $image->image;

}

// dd($images);

$data       = rekap::find($id);
$folderName = $data->id.'-'.str_replace(' ', '-',$data->customer);
$zip        = new ZipArchive;
$zipFile    = public_path().'/image_rekap/'.$folderName.'/'.$folderName.'.zip';

if ($zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
{

    //add files into a zip
    foreach ($images as $key => $value) {

        //replace word "full" with $portfolioImage->id
        $relativeNameInZipFile = str_replace('full',$key,basename($value));
        $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
    }

    $zip->close();
}

return response()->download($zipFile);
```

and this my `route`

```
Route::get('/download_image/{id}',[RekapController::class, 'download_image'])->name('download_image')->middleware('auth');
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: It looks like your Code in the Blade file is wrong. It has no property of id. So it would be more interesting to see the controllers show method, that is rendering the blade file in the first instance. 
    <a href="/download_image/{{ $images->id (error occuring here) }}" class="btn btn-primary center">DOWNLOAD</a>

maybe you want to iterate through the images collection and show for each image model? for this just modify the code to: 
@foreach($images as $image)
    <a href="/download_image/{{ $image->id }}" class="btn btn-primary center">DOWNLOAD</a>
@endforeach

Comment: And I've updated `blade` in full. I want to make a button beside the `kembali` button how do I do that. @Krytech

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably coming from this line

```
<button href="/download_image/{{ $images->id }}" class="btn btn-primary center">DOWNLOAD</button>
```

You are trying to access `$imageS->id` and `$images` doesn't have an `id` property. It's obvious WHY. Try removing this line of code and watch the error disappear. Or put it in the foreach loop like so

```
          @foreach ($images as $image)
          <button href="/download_image/{{ $image->id }}" class="btn btn-primary center">DOWNLOAD</button>
          <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="card" style="max-width: 50rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <img src="{{asset('images_rekap/'.$image->image)}}" class="card-img-top mb-2">
                      <a href="/deleteimagerekap/{{ $image->id }}" class="btn btn-primary center">HAPUS</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
           @endforeach
```